# What changed writing files to a mounted volume in Windows 8.1

Tags: java, windows, usb

We manufacture a device that connects to a PC via USB and presents itself as a mounted volume. This device acts as a bridge between the PC and another device which receives a configuration file. A Java Web Start application on the PC fetches a configuration file from a web service and places it on the mounted volume. A small piece of firmware in a PIC chip on our device (the one with the mounted volume) fetches the file and sends it on to the target device. This has been working without issue for 6 1/2 years. But when used on Windows 8.1 our target device consistently reports it as a bad file. We discovered we can work around this by having our java web start app write the file to a local temp folder then copy it to the mounted volume rather than writing it to the mounted volume directly from the web service. So I'm wondering if anyone knows what changed in Windows 8.1 and why it works to write the file to a temp folder first.

Comment: Just a very random thought, depending on how you download the file in question, this could be related to the [Persistent Zone Identifiert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537029.aspx), that gets stored in an alternate data stream of the downloaded file. Explorer uses this information to allow or restrict certain types of access to a file.

Comment: Thank for the thought, IInspectable. Will need to take some time to check into this. I appreciate your taking the time to respond.